# Display dialog while jquery datatables is working on pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables, partial-views

I'm working on jQuery datatables using asp.net mvc, I have thousands of rows that make the datatable to work on pagination in about 3-5 seconds.

What I want is to show a dialog that shows that the table is currently working on the paging.

What I am trying to do right now is to show a dialog using a partial view with ajax. ***But the problem is that the dialog is being shown after the datatable is done working***. Is there something I can do so that the datatables continue to work on paging while the dialog is showing, then after that close the dialog?

Here's some snippets of what I am working on:

```
$("#runButton").click(function() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("Loading")';
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        //Start of Dialog
        $.Dialog({
            sysButtons: { btnClose: false },
            overlay: true,
            shadow: true,
            padding: 10,
            height: 75,
            width: 300,
            flat: true,
            onShow: function (_dialog) {
                $.Dialog.title("Test Dialog");
                $.Dialog.content(data);
                $.Metro.initAll();
            }
        });
    })

    showTable();
})

function showTable() {
    var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
            "deferRender": true,

            "columnDefs": [
                { "visible": false, "targets": 2 }
            ],
            "order": [[2, 'asc']],
            "drawCallback": function (settings) {
                var api = this.api();
                var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
                var last = null;

                api.column(2, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group, i) {
                    if (last !== group) {
                        $(rows).eq(i).before(
                            '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">' + group + '</td></tr>'
                        );
                        last = group;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
}
```

***--EDIT--***

I am doing some troubleshooting, I tried to use simple dialog and put the initialization of table inside the dialog function:

```
$("#runButton").click(function() {
    ("#dialog").dialog({
    open: function () {
        showTable();
    }
});
```

});

Still the same issue, the datables still run first after it is done, that's the time the dialog appears. What do I need to do so that dialog will come up first, and then let the datatables finish its work and close the dialog. Please help, thank you!

Comment: What initializes the dialog in the first place?

Comment: please see my edit. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try combining this in the first `click` function you have? You don't want to have two `click` functions for the same div. `("#dialog").dialog({
    open: function () {
        showTable();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

1.show the main page,in the main page,there is a button(or something else),click it will show a empty dialog.
2.after the empty dialog shown,begin an ajax request to load list.
3.in the list,have some link to page 2,page 3.....
4.when click a page link,clear the dialog to empty,and begin a ajax to load page 2(or 3,or 4....)
5.when ajax loaded,put it into dialog div
you can change the empty diaolog to a loading icon
you can use @Ajax.ActionLink(...) to do this eazy
the AjaxOptions has some property UpdateTargetId,OnBegin,OnSuccess...you can use these to do something more

Comment: thank you for trying to help, but I don't understand your answer and I think it's a different approach than what I am doing right now.